# Why do I see changes from another branch when I switch to master?

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I did `git checkout -b profile` and made some changes on that branch.

I don't like those changes and want to get back my code from the `master` branch without the changes from the `profile` branch.

However, when I do `git checkout master`, I see the changes from the `profile` branch.

Is there a way to get the previous code back?

Comment: can you clarify "I still see the changes from profile branch". Does it mean that you still see those changes in your editor, or that `git status` shows uncommitted files?

`git checkout .` will discard any unstaged changes.

Comment: I see them in editor.

Comment: if you see them in the editor only, and `git status` shows nothing, you just might need to reopen the files.

if `git status` is empty, and you still see the unwanted changes, please make sure you are on a correct branch and then run `git log` just to be sure you haven't accidentally commited a change to `master`.

Comment: If the file is open in the editor, your editor still has an open reference to the file it opened, not the file that `git checkout` *replaced* it with. That is, `git checkout` doesn't edit a file in-place; it copies a new file (out of the repository) into your working directory, using the same name.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the changes because the changes are not commited in `profile` branch.

Try the following commands reset your `master` branch:

```
git checkout master
git pull
git reset --hard origin/master
```

It will reset your local `master` branch with the repo `master`

Apart from the above, you can remove the unwanted changes from the following command

```
git checkout file1name file2name
```

If you want to remove all changes which are not commited, you can use

```
git checkout .
```